# Is considering only one output for each input for function a convention, or is it a reflection of the reality of the world?

Tags: functions

I'm reading algebra from [brilliant](https://brilliant.org/courses/graphing-and-modeling/function-fundamentals/function-notation-2/2/) and it defines function as:

> A function is a relationship where every allowed input results in exactly **one** output — there's no choice.

My question is, what makes that limitation? Is it a convention we human beings considered (maybe to simplify stuff) or is it a real thing?

A similar concept in physics would be the charge of the electron. We know that there is something that pulls or pushes (the reality), but naming one positive and the other negative is totally arbitrary and only a convention.

Comment: It is merely a definition. There is also a notion of a [multi-valued function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function) or a [set-valued function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-valued_function) which can each be thought of as having multiple outputs for a given input; or on the other end a [partial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function) which may have zero outputs for a given input.

Comment: @PrincessEev then we end up with a contradiction. A **set-valued function** is a **function**. Yet a function can not have more than one output. I know I'm being silly here. But each time I'm trying to learn science and math, these stupid small points deter me. I think somebody someday has made a definition and no one has ever thought of fixing it. And now we need to learn a lot of contradictions which makes it really hard.

Comment: @PrincessEev, in software development, we have fixed it. A function is one that takes an input and produces an output that can be nothing. I wish mathematicians would also use this definition in the world of math.

Comment: "then we end up with a contradiction. A set-valued function is a function" -- Your issue lies with semantics and grammar, not mathematics. As far as mathematics cares, the two entities are distinct with different definitions; a set-valued function does not lie in a special subset of functions. If it makes you more comfortable, the "typical" type of function is (somewhat uncommonly) called a "total function", further emphasizing the difference.

Comment: (Well, I guess you could say that set-valued functions are functions from a domain to some power set, but that's also somewhat ignoring the spirit and point of them as having multiple values.)

Comment: @SaeedNeamati Let me just cautious that CS functions and math functions are completely different objects, despite having the same name!

Comment: @Yanko, how are they different? They both take input, do something on it, anf deliver an output. Can you please clarify the differences?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati I think one difference is that the CS function may give different values to the same number (similar, but not quite as you asked in your question). For instance if my function is "SUM" and I input $1$ it will output $1$, when I will input $1$ again it will output $2$ and so on...

Comment: @SaeedNeamati I guess doing something like "$1+1 = 2 +1  = 3$" is "valid" in the CS world, but not in the math world because $1+1\not = 3$.